# google identity move from webview -> is there agreement from apple on using the system browser?

Tags: ios, google-api, google-oauth

Do you have confirmation from Apple that the App Review team will not reject apps that use this authentication technique? I ask because I have integrated with an earlier version of this library that launched safari to login, and my app was rejected from the store because it was supposedly a worse user experience.

I argued that logging in through safari was actually better, because it gave users confidence that they were not being phished, but that argument was rejected, and I spent a week hacking together something with a webview to get approval.
http://www.shankari.org/2015/02/google-ios-sdk-cannot-be-used-without.html

Before I start this again, I'd like confirmation that the google identity team has reached out to the apple team and got their approval for their proposed solution. Ideally, this would be publicly documented so that I can cite it if my app is rejected.

Shankari

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack can not tell you if google contacted Apple.   Try google support forums.

Comment: @DaImTo normally I'd agree with you, but in this case [Google actually advises users](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html) to ask "questions related to the migration on StackOverflow, tagged with google-oauth". That's how I came here in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Google Sign-in for iOS uses `SFSafariViewController`, rather than Safari on iOS 9 & 10. `SFSafariViewController` shares many of the benefits that Safari had (such as the user likely already being logged in to Google), with the additional usability improvement that the user doesn't leave your app.

There are many recently updated apps on the store that do this, for example, try:

- NY Times (Settings -> Login -> Google)
- Google Maps (Settings -> Add Account)
- Pokémon Go (Sign in)